# How to trigger browser notifications request on a specific action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, notifications

As soon as a person comes to my site they are confronted with...

[image]

But I only want that popup to occur after a user clicks "Push" so that the user may understand the context of the request.

[image]

How to only trigger the browser notification request upon a user clicking "Push"?

I implemented push via [serviceworker gem](https://github.com/rossta/serviceworker-rails), [webpush gem](https://github.com/zaru/webpush), [VAPID tutorial](https://rossta.net/blog/using-the-web-push-api-with-vapid.html).

```
<%= form_for(@challenge)  do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box :push %>
  <label for="challenge_push">Push <%= image_tag "laptop.png" %></label>
<% end %>
```

**application.js**

```
// Let's check if the browser supports notifications
if (!("Notification" in window)) {
  console.error("This browser does not support desktop notification");
}

// Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
  console.log("Permission to receive notifications has been granted");
}

// Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
  Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
  // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
    if (permission === "granted") {
      console.log("Permission to receive notifications has been granted");
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Wrap your notification asking part from application.js with function.
Then add that function to click handlers of Push button.

```
  const askForNotification = () => {
    //you code here
  }

  pushButton.addEventListener("click", askForNotification)
```